# Reconciling De Broglie wavelength with relativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have trouble understanding what a De Broglie wavelength means when differing frames of reference are taken into account.

Observers in differing frames of reference will see a particle's wavelength as being different. I think I understand a matter wave as similar to a probability wave, but what impact does it have on my understanding when probability becomes relative?  Does this mean different observers have a different probability of finding a particle at a position?

This might seem silly, but I am at rest relative to myself, do I have a definable wavelength from my own frame of reference even though observers will see a matter wave?

Comment: What do you mean by probability becoming relative? Apart from that the "probability wave" meme is a very bad way of describing quantum mechanics. A probability is the hypothetical convergence point of the frequency of outcomes of an infinite number of experiments. It's a number that one observer hands to another observer on a piece of paper, it's not a physical quantity. Why would a number on paper change just because you hand it to someone on a moving train?

Comment: No, the wavelength of a matter wave is frame dependent. This is totally normal because the wavelength is related to momentum, and momentum is certainly frame-dependent. So is energy, frequency, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The De Broglie wavelength corresponds to a free particle's momentum, $\bf p=\hbar \bf k$, and a particle's observed momentum obviously depends on it's velocity relative to the observer.

The localization probability, on the other hand, is given by the wave function $\psi$ as $|\psi|^2$. But for a free particle $\psi \sim e^{i(\bf k \cdot\bf x -\omega t)}$ and the localization probability is uniform in space (albeit infinitesimal), regardless of the observer's reference frame.

In the particle's rest frame the wavelength becomes infinite (zero momentum) and the wave function simply oscillates in time as $e^{-i\omega t}$.

For wave packets that are no longer uniformly distributed throughout 3D-space, the localization probability will look different for different observers, but this is no different then a localized light pulse looking different in different frames.